# C++ : parentheses ignored when evaluating sequential operators

Tags: c++, comma-operator, g++4.8

First of all, I must say that the problem raised here is solved for me, and I wonder :

- what I have misunderstood,
- if the compiler has an error (I know this is rare) (it is gcc 4.8.4).

---

I want to calculate the norm of a 2-dimentional vector, of which coordinates are computed only at that moment. Let's say, I want to calculate || (x0, y0) - (x1, y1) || , by the formula sqrt((x0-x1)**2 + (y0-y1)**2) . Only the result needs to be saved.

For performance reasons, the square is done by self-multiplication, and I want the substractions and access to variables to be done only once. I want the total to be efficient at runtime, and somehow elegantly coded. I have thought three possibilities :

- repeat twice `x0 - x1` and `y0 - y1`, and hope the optimization step of the compilator will detect the repetition,
- use an inline function,
- use together a buffer variable and the sequential operator.

I decided to try the last option.

---

Consider now the following code :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float x0 (-1), x1 (2), y0 (13), y1 (9), result, tmp;

    result = std::sqrt ((tmp = x0 - x1, tmp * tmp) + (tmp = y0 - y1, tmp * tmp));
    printf ("%f\n", result);
}
```

I know I must obtain `5.000000`, but I obtain `5.656854`, which is sqrt((y0-y1)**2 + ((y0-y1)**2)).

I can get the wanted result with :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float x0 (-1), x1 (2), y0 (13), y1 (9), result, tmp, tmp2;

    result = std::sqrt ((tmp = x0 - x1, tmp * tmp) + (tmp2 = y0 - y1, tmp2 * tmp2));
    printf ("%f\n", result);
}
```

It is like the first parts of the sequential operators are evaluated at first, ignoring the parentheses and the return value of the first sequential operator. Seems a bit akward ; is there something in the definition of C++ that I missed here ?

NB : Setting the optimization on or off changes nothing during the test.

Comment: Your code is not readable nor elegant. You don't have to do everything in one line.

Comment: That looks like undefined behavior in the first example. There is no guarantee that `tmp` will be modified in the correct sequence.

Comment: Parentheses specify how operations are grouped, to override operator precedence. It doesn't have any effect on the order of evaluating the subexpressions, though.

Comment: You're modifying `tmp` and using it in the same expression. Trying to do everything in one statement gains you nothing, and is causing all sorts of chaos in terms of readability (or lack thereof) and this bug.

Comment: I would consider creating a function `double norm(double dx, double dy)` and call it as `result = norm(x0 - x1, y0 - y1)` to get rid of the temporary variables and generally improve clarity. Or just use `hypot(x0 - x1, y0 - y1)`.

Comment: Also, the optimizer will most likely keep the result of `x0-x1` in a register and re-use the result. Examine the compiler output if you're not convinced.

Comment: Thank you for these quick answers ! The problem is what I was believing it to be... Before writing this post, I decided to use an inline function. I was not knowing about the `std::hypot` function, thank you Roel for the tip !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both sides of the `operator +` may be evaluated interleaved. In particular, each of the two assignments in the parenthesis must happen before the multiplication to its immediate right (in correct code that is, which your first variant is not), but need not happen before the other assignment. Also, the other assignment is allowed to happen in between one assignment and the matching multiplication.

Your first variant thus invokes undefined behavior because it contains two unsequenced modification of `tmp`. So literally every result is legal, including a crash or NaN.

In general, please keep in mind that "your code is clever" is not a compliment. Keep it simple, if you really must optimize away the subtractions (you most likely do not):

```
auto dx = x0 - x1;
auto dy = y0 - y1;
auto result = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
result = std::sqrt ((tmp = x0 - x1, tmp * tmp) + (tmp = y0 - y1, tmp * tmp));
```

You should avoid modifying a value that you use elsewhere in the same expression. Most operators are not guaranteed to evaluate their operands in any particular order (the exceptions are &&, ||, ?:, and the comma operator). In this case, the operands of the + operator in this expression could be evaluated in any order and not necessarily all at once, so your code has undefined behavior.

Furthermore, unless you've profiled your code and know that you need a particular statement to be tightly optimized, you should prefer clarity over clever tricks.